# GDB to do find pointers in a given memory area

Tags: python, memory, gdb

I want to input Python script into GDB，this script is used to create a new command，assuming its name as 'fp'， its function is to search in a given memory area, to check whether this area contains the pointers which are in the program，if there are pointers in this memory area，the command will print the address of the pointers and print the address pointed by the pointer。

example：

（gdb）fp 0x442032 100 
(the first parameter is the start address，100 is the size for searching）

If there is a pointer called S in the debugging program, its address is 0x442033 and points to the address of 0x442039，so the output should be:

0x442033 --> 0x442039

My question is how can I use GDB to find the pointers' addresses? How to realize this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for the GDB built-in `find` command. Documentation [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Searching-Memory.html).

> If there is a pointer called S in the debugging program, its address is 0x442033

If there is a pointer `S`, its address is almost certainly not `0x442033`, because loading unaligned data carries a significant performance penalties.

If you are looking to find "any" pointer in the given memory (which the `find` would not do), you are probably doing something wrong: any non-trivial program will have 100s or 1000s of pointers, and looking for "any" (rather than a specific pointer you are interested in) may be a sign that you don't understand your program.

Comment: I want to find the pointers in the given memory areas, no matter the pointers represent "s" or others, I just want to find all of the pointers in the area, is it possible? Because the assignment is this: use python script and create a gdb command, let it can identify all of  pointers in a given memory area.